# IIS FTP same user authorized on HOST1, not authorized on HOST2

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, ftp

I recently switched web hosting companies for my website. I have a PHP application that connects to a Windows FTP (IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard) that now won't do anything. No passwords or configs were changed on the FTP. Included logs from before and after the switch.

Before:

```
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP - FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP - FTP_IP 21 USER FTP_USER 331 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 /
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 CWD /OutToHost 250 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 /OutToHost
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 TYPE A 200 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PORT XX,XX,XX,XX,143,94 200 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 NLST . 226 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 /OutToHost
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PWD - 257 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:00:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 e459623e-4140-4c47-9fab-98c300c3a053 -
2013-11-16 00:01:01 OLD_IP - FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
2013-11-16 00:01:01 OLD_IP - FTP_IP 21 USER FTP_USER 331 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
2013-11-16 00:01:01 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a /
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 CWD /OutToHost 250 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a /OutToHost
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 TYPE A 200 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PORT XX,XX,XX,XX,198,3 200 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 NLST . 226 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a /OutToHost
2013-11-16 00:01:02 OLD_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PWD - 257 0 0 a477ac1c-fe49-414d-997c-47ea3b6ac80a -
```

After:

```
2013-11-18 12:59:52 NEW_IP - FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP - FTP_IP 21 USER FTP_USER 331 0 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 /
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 CWD /OutToHost 250 0 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 /OutToHost
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 TYPE A 200 0 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PORT YY,YY,YY,YY,231,244 200 0 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP - FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP - FTP_IP 21 USER FTP_USER 331 0 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd /
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 TYPE A 200 0 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd -
2013-11-18 12:59:53 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 PORT YY,YY,YY,YY,172,174 200 0 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd -
2013-11-18 13:00:14 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 NLST . 550 4294967295 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 /OutToHost
2013-11-18 13:00:14 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 STOR 20131118070002.ord 550 4294967295 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd /20131118070002.ord
2013-11-18 13:01:23 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 64 0 a03a277b-8736-46c1-8645-d2f806e53c56 -
2013-11-18 13:01:23 NEW_IP DOMAIN\FTP_USER FTP_IP 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 64 0 b01f53c4-8669-4e93-bf0d-18aaecb596bd -
```

Answer (score 0):

Firewall issue on the new server. Didn't think this would be a firewall thing since it was able to create the initial connection to the FTP server, but I was wrong.